# How to aggregate data Month-on-Month or Year-on-Year using aggregate query in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have objects in my bookings collection. Structure of the object is as follows:

```
{
    "_id": "asdkbasdkjcbhsajcbh",
    "created_at": 1662712231,
    "total_teus": 4,
    ...
}
```

I want to write a query which gives me Month-on-Month or Year-on-Year sum of total_teus sold. I tried my hands but failed.

I wrote the following query:

```
    db.bookings.aggregate([{
        "$match": {
            "created_at": {
                "$gte": 1648771200
            },
            "company_id": {
                "$nin": ["ln_exports1582702220", "marico_limited1588656327", "star_fisheries_pvt_ltd1576862831", "td_infotech1569314187", "Xportify1561638979", "msuyash1572972166", "demo_account1587548110", "production_testing1586152669", "abc_tech_pvt._ltd.1571657756"]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "created_date_long": {
                "$toLong": "$created_at"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "created_date": {
                "$toDate": "$created_date_long"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
          "_id": {
            "$dateToString": {
              "date": "$created_date",
              "format": "%Y-%m"
            }
          },
          "teus_exported": {
            "$sum": "$total_teus"
          }  
        }
    }
])
```

When I ran this query, I got the following result:

```
{
    "_id": "1970-01",
    "teus_exported": 234
}
```

I want result to look like this:

```
[{
    "_id": "1970-01",
    "teus_exported": 234
},
{
    "_id": "1970-02",
    "teus_exported": 654
},
{
    "_id": "1970-03",
    "teus_exported": 623
}]
```

**Can someone throw some light as to where my query is going wrong?**

Comment: You need to multiply your long by 1000, as it is in seconds, and `$dateToString` expect milliseconds.

Comment: I tried multiplied it by 1000 but it is throwing an error: $multiply only supports numeric types, not date. 
{
  _id: {
    $dateToString: {
      "date": {"$multiply": ["$created_date", 1000]},
      "format": "%Y-%m"
    }
  },
  teus_exported: {
    "$sum": "$total_teus"
  }  
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to multiply your `created_at` by 1000, as it is in seconds, and $dateToString expect milliseconds:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "created_at": {
        "$gte": 1648771200
      },
      "company_id": {
        "$nin": [
          "ln_exports1582702220",
          "marico_limited1588656327",
          "star_fisheries_pvt_ltd1576862831",
          "td_infotech1569314187",
          "Xportify1561638979",
          "msuyash1572972166",
          "demo_account1587548110",
          "production_testing1586152669",
          "abc_tech_pvt._ltd.1571657756"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {$addFields: {
      created_date: {
        $dateToString: {
          date: {$toDate: {$multiply: ["$created_at", 1000]}},
          format: "%Y-%m"
        }
      }
  }},
  {$group: {_id: "$created_date", teus_exported: {$sum: "$total_teus"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KI_VxET_ldF)